# My code keeps looping the last part and won't print

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a college student working on making a program that displays the temperature by, after pressing a button, turning on a certain LED that will then light in either in a flashing or solid manner and then, after 7 seconds, print out the current temperature. The code also requires that I implement repetition structures and conditional statements. For some reason, however, it only loops the last part of my code and doesn't print out the temperature as instructed. I feel like I have been forgetting to implement a few functions, but I've been having a really hard time understanding what's happening in the class. Below is the code I've been working on. If possible, try to explain like I'm a 5 year old. Thank you very much.

```
# Name: Madeleine
# Assignment: Temperature Notification
# Description:
#
# Revision  Date        Initials    Description of Changes

import pps_emu
import time

sensor = pps_emu.Sensor()

def main():

     print("Welcome! Please enter the temperature, then press Button 1.")

     ftemp = sensor.input('temp')
     ctemp = (ftemp - 32) * 5/9


     while sensor.input('Button_1') == 'pressed':

         if ftemp in range(-50, 32):
          for t in range(0, 7, 1):
           sensor.output('bled', 'on')
           time.sleep(.5)
           sensor.output('bled', 'off')
           time.sleep(.5)
           print("EXTREMELY cold")

         elif ftemp in range(33, 50):
          sensor.output('bled', 'on')
          time.sleep(7)
          print("cold")

         elif ftemp in range(51, 70):
          sensor.output('yled', 'on')
          time.sleep(7)
          print("normal")

         elif ftemp in range(71, 90):
          sensor.output('gled', 'on')
          time.sleep(7)
          print("warm")

         elif ftemp in range(91, 100):
          sensor.output('rled', 'on')
          time.sleep(7)
          print("hot")

     else:
      print("EXTREMELY hot")
      for t in range(0, 7, 1):
        sensor.output('rled', 'on')
        time.sleep(.5)
        sensor.output('rled', 'off')
        time.sleep(.5)

     print("The current temperature in fahrenheit is {.2f}°F".format(ftemp))
     print("The current temperature in celsius is {.2f}°C".format(ctemp))


 # Tell the Python interpreter to execute this main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Comment: it sounds like it never achieves logical True on this fragment `while sensor.input('Button_1') == 'pressed':`. Under the corresponding `else:` clause, print out the value of `sensor.input('Button_1')` to see what it holds, or if it is understood by the program.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that, but thanks for replying.

Comment: So, when do you want it to print the temperature? Every 7 seconds while the button is pressed? Or just every 7 seconds in general?

Comment: No, the light is supposed to stay on for seven seconds after the button is pressed, and then it displays the temperature.

Comment: Where is the button_1?  Are you on some type of lab platform or are you using an arduino?

Comment: I'm using pycharm, but the code is supposed to work in a physical programming simulator

Comment: The program will output `EXTREMELY hot` if `ftemp < 51` once the main problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

What [CodeMantle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5738287/codemantle) said seems correct. But I will try to simplify it. In line `20` of your code, `sensor.input("Button_1")` never becomes equal to `"pressed"`.
The indentation (way of organizing code with spaces, more info [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php)) is not quite correct, meaning that your `if ... else ...` statement becomes a `while ... else ...` statement.

A `while ... else ...` means that the `else` statement runs when the `while` loop stops.
Based on your description, the `while` statement in your code stops running because `sensor.input("Button_1")` is not equal to `"pressed"` and moves on to the code inside the `else` statement. The way to fix it would be to fix your indentation. This would make sure that no code runs if `sensor.input("Button_1")` is not equal to `"pressed"`.

To see why `sensor.input("Button_1")` is not equal to `"pressed"`, you will need to print the value of `sensor.input("Button_1")` by adding

```py
print("Sensor Input for Button_1:", sensor.input("Button_1"))
```

to the line 19. This will display on the terminal what the value of `sensor.input("Button_1")`. With that, you can then find out what is wrong, I can't really help with the rest because I don't have a Raspberry PI.

This code is an attempt to try to help.

```py
# Name: Madeleine
# Assignment: Temperature Notification
# Description:
#
# Revision  Date        Initials    Description of Changes

import pps_emu
import time

sensor = pps_emu.Sensor()

def main():
  print("Welcome! Please enter the temperature, then press Button 1.")

  ftemp = sensor.input('temp')
  ctemp = (ftemp - 32) * 5/9

  print("Sensor Input for Button_1:", sensor.input("Button_1"))

  while sensor.input('Button_1') == 'pressed':
    if ftemp in range(-50, 32):
      for t in range(0, 7, 1):
        sensor.output('bled', 'on')
        time.sleep(.5)
        sensor.output('bled', 'off')
        time.sleep(.5)
        print("EXTREMELY cold")

    elif ftemp in range(33, 50):
      sensor.output('bled', 'on')
      time.sleep(7)
      print("cold")

    elif ftemp in range(51, 70):
      sensor.output('yled', 'on')
      time.sleep(7)
      print("normal")

    elif ftemp in range(71, 90):
      sensor.output('gled', 'on')
      time.sleep(7)
      print("warm")

    elif ftemp in range(91, 100):
      sensor.output('rled', 'on')
      time.sleep(7)
      print("hot")

    else:
      print("EXTREMELY hot")
      for t in range(0, 7, 1):
        sensor.output('rled', 'on')
        time.sleep(.5)
        sensor.output('rled', 'off')
        time.sleep(.5)

    print("The current temperature in fahrenheit is {}°F".format(ftemp))
    print("The current temperature in celsius is {}°C".format(ctemp))

    # I'm not exactly sure if you want a break statement but unless you want the application running forever, always add a break.
    break # Delete this line if you don't want to add the break statement (and probably the line above this)


 # Tell the Python interpreter to execute this main()
if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```